# escape % in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I want to make an sql statement -

```
sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM movies where title like '%%@%'",searchKeyword];
```

But sqlStatement is becoming -

"SELECT * FROM movies where title like '%@'"

I want to make it

"SELECT * FROM movies where title like '%searchKeyword%'"

How can I escape the "%" character?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try :

```
sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM movies where title like '%%%@%%'",searchKeyword];
```

"%%" is the way of printing the '%' character.

Comment: I'm waiting for 'little Bobby Tables - the movie' to come out.